# Reinstall new copy of ubuntu 14.04 keeping my data and installed programs

Tags: 14.04, xubuntu

How can I reinstall Ubuntu 14.04 on Ubuntu 14.04 without losing my installed programs and data if I can?

Answer (score 0):

Yep it can be done but Ubuntu Install will reinstall your packages 
**This is no guarantee that you will have all your packages as the way you left it**. **I would Still back up the Data**

I don't think you will lose any of your data as long as you use the same user name you once had.

Boot into You live/CD/USB Setup

When you get here select something else and click <kbd>Contiune</kbd>
[image]

click on your partition you installed Ubuntu on then click <kbd>Change</kbd>

Now be very careful on what you do here

Change the USE as to your File system mines `ext4`

[image]

Use the same mount point as in your other install. mine mount is `/` then click <kbd>OK</kbd>

[image]

Then this window will pop up. click on <kbd>Go back</kbd>

[image]

Now you can click on install now  **Use you same user name.**

[image]

Comment: :Thank you very much! I will try it after copying my data and let you know if have any issue.